# FileNotFoundException error

Tags: java, javabeans

when i am trying to copy the .pdf file i am getting FileNotFoundException I am using this coding in my framework.This is my part of coding in my framework. Please could help me any one.If you need any other information just ask me..

```
 public  void copyFile(String dir, String file) {

        try{
            Debug.println("System.getProperty(\"reporthome\")"+System.getProperty("reporthome"));
            File path = new File(System.getProperty("reporthome")+"\\jreports\\fileimport\\"+file);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            Debug.println("dir+\"\\\\\"+file"+dir+"\\"+file);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir+"\\"+file);
            int i = 0;
            while( (i = fis.read()) != -1){
                fos.write(i);
            }
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
            path.delete();
        }catch(IOException io){
            Debug.println(" Exception while copying file: "+io);
        }

     }
```

Comment: add a if (path.exists()) and check if it exists

Comment: First of all replace all "\\" with File.separator and try once

Comment: Which file is not found? file *file* or file *path* ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public  void copyFile(String dir, String file) {

    try{
        Debug.println("System.getProperty(\"reporthome\")"+System.getProperty("reporthome"));
        File path = new File(System.getProperty("reporthome")+"\\jreports\\fileimport\\"+file);
    if (path.exists()){ 
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir+"\\"+file);
        int i = 0;
        while( (i = fis.read()) != -1){
        fos.write(i);
        }
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
        path.delete();
     } else{
    Debug.println("Path doesn't exist : "+ path);
     }

    }catch(IOException io){
        Debug.println(" Exception while copying file: "+io);
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the file in the directory you are trying to copy it from? Are you able to Debug your code? I mean, if you are using Eclipse, its fairly easy to put breakpoints and inspect your code for this particular exception.